# column Array, Offset Find Value, Count

Tags: vba

i have data in Column "I", some text values, different, I want to add them to an Array, then go 2 columns back and if there the value is "Check" then Count it.The Array should Show me my values from column "I" and how many "Check" per each. I did something like this below, but probably it is completely wrong...just trying something, don't really know how to finish...The results may be displayd then in column A:B

```
  Sub CCount()
    Dim Count, Count, Count1 As Long
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountA("I9:I32")
    Cells(9, 9).Select
    Count = 0
    ReDim Arr(1 To n)
    For Each Arr(n) In Range("I9:I32")

    If Arr(n).Value = Arr(n) And Arr(n).Offset(0, -2).Value = "Check" Then
    Count = Arr(n).Count
    Count1 = Count + Count1
    End If
    Next Arr(n)

    End Sub
```

Sorry, see below a Picture....I want to count following: For Each Target, Count if "Check", so for Target1 = 3, Target3 = 1 and so on...There are like 20 different values in Column "Target"

[image]

Comment: Your description is poor at best. Please add a picture of your workbook at-least. Detail what you are trying to do, such as "I would like to find the values in column X and see if they exist in column Y". The code helps but some sample data would be helpful along with some desired results.

Comment: sorry, for description, the Picture could help

Comment: Copy your data from the target column to your output column, use remove duplicates then use countifs to get the counts.

Comment: yes, I could do it also with a simple Pivot...but wanted to do it with a code